# Python IDLE change highlighting theme

Tags: python-idle

I am using a Mac and I have no idea how I can change the highlighing theme in Python IDLE (Python's Integrated Development Environment).

I want to change it to the following colors:

```
> https://pastebin.com/54h6U91Q
```

Sublime Text theme colors.

Any help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: if you want a monokai theme,please visit https://gist.github.com/jaimergp/10285906
,hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure all IDLE instances are closed, then in your home folder (`~`) there should be a 'hidden' folder called `.idlerc` - if it doesn't exist, create it.

In that folder edit or create a file named `config-highlight.cfg` add to it:

```
[SublimeText]
```

and paste your colors after it (from the quick glance it seems to match IDLEs color scheme config). Then edit/create a file named `config-main.cfg` and make sure it has its theme section as:

```
[Theme]
default = 0
name = SublimeText
```

Comment: Yes thank you, I was actually able to find the hidden folder .idlerc by using TinkerTool, although now my IDLE doesn't want to open, it says "The application IDLE could not be opened.", I've reinstalled it two times and restarted my computer two times, didn't fix it. I can't really find a fix in Google either, I'll keep searching. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I believe that this message is coming from OSX, not IDLE.  Try running IDLE in a console with `python -m idlelib.idle` and you should get a message from IDLE.  If nothing else, delete any files you edited.

Answer (score 1):

@zwer gave the fast (and a bit dangerous) answer, which I have used.  Here is the slow and safer answer, which I have also used.  On the menu, select Options => Configure IDLE > Highlighting tab.  Pick the current theme closest to your target.  Make changes, one at a time.  Save.  The new theme should be your selected custom theme.You can make more changes and save with the same name.